# How to exclude from zipgroupfileset?

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am using ANT 1.7.1 but I am getting an error that exclude is not supported in zipgroupfileset target.

I am trying to do below operation -

```
<zipgroupfileset >
                <fileset dir="lib">
                <excludes>
         <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
         <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
         <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>                                       
                </excludes>

            </fileset>
   </zipgroupfileset>
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) is already a fileset, so all you need is something like:

```
<zipgroupfileset dir="lib" excludes="META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA"/>
```

Comment: Tried this  <zipgroupfileset >
     <fileset dir="lib">
    <excludes>META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA</excludes>
      </fileset>
      </zipgroupfileset> but it says zipgroupfileset does not support fileset

Comment: <zipgroupfileset dir="lib"  >
                           <exclude name="META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.RSA"/>
                 </zipgroupfileset> This does work but I am still getting security exceptions

Comment: @BChawla YOu also have to remove the signatures from MANIFEST.MF

Comment: This did not work. I have tried with the same for excluding few folders when `zipgroupfileset` is build.

Comment: The `excludes` attribute in `zipgroupfileset` filters the archives but not their *contents*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593838/3826702 for details

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer didn't work for me, I did the following:

```
    <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" excludes="<jars containing the signatures>"/>
    <zipfileset src="lib/<jar containing the signatures>" excludes="META-INF/*.SF,META-INF/*.DSA"/>
```

This solution requires you to know which jars has been signed (contains .SF,*.DSA,*.RSA) files. You'll need a zipfileset for each of those jars.

zipgroupfileset cannot inspect the contents of the jars.