# Exclude Jar from Ant Build using zipgroupfileset

Tags: java, servlets, ant, jar

I have created a Jar Project which contains `Filter`.
I need to use `servlet-api.jar` when I compile the `Filter` code.

But when I want to use the Jar in another application, I want to build the jar in such a way that it will exclude `servlet-api.jar`.

I am using Apache Ant with NetBeans 8:
I have added below code in `build.xml`.

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <jar destfile="dist/MyJar.jar">
        <zipfileset src="dist/MyJarAsLibrary.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib/." excludes="javax/*"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

I have used Apache Ant [zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html).
But I searched on google I found the excludes for files.
I tried with excluding the servlet packages as `javax/*`, but it did not work.
No Idea how to exclude specific packages.
I found few excludes with `zipfileset`, but I need to use `zipgroupfileset` and exclude the `javax.servelt.*` packages.

Comment: Try `excludes` with two asterisks: `excludes="javax/**"`

Comment: Hi, I tried with the option you given for `"javax/**"`. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `excludes` attribute of `zipgroupfileset` is used to select the archives to pick entries from, not to filter the contents of the archives. `zipgroupfileset` always contains everything included inside the matched archives.

The simple solution if you know which archive contains the servlet classes is to exclude it from the `zipgroupfileset` and add an explicit `zipfileset`.

If you don't know the archive, you can mimic `zipgroupfileset` using the `archives` resource collection and wrap that into a `restrict` container. Something like

```
<restrict>
  <archives>
    <zips>
      <fileset dir="dist/lib/"/>
    </zips>
  </archives>
  <not>
    <name name="javax/servlet/*"/>
  </not>
</restrict>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately this is _very_ slow when a few thousand files are filtered (~10 mins). Any idea if there’s some other pattern that ant processes faster?

Comment: yes, `archives`' implementation is known to be quite inefficient (it opens and closes the archive once for each entry). A quicker solution is to extract all the files into a temporary directory and use a vanilla `fileset` from there. As far as I know there is no "many files" solution that worked without a temporary folder short of implementing your own task for that.